# Linux Computer with two NIC on the same subnet mask

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, networkmanager

Trying to configure a machine with two NIC with different IP addresses on but on the same subnet. only one ip is reachable and the other is not

ifconfig shows the following

```
eno1 ip 192.168.0.100 netmask 255.255.0.0
eno2 ip 192.168.0.101 netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

Do i need to set ip table ? if so how is this done ?

Comment: Is the interface up? What does `ip link` show you?

Comment: Any reason why you are using 2 physical interfaces? You could use sub-interfaces and it should work. I've had a few all running, same subnet, same card, without issue.

Comment: eno1 shows <BROADCAST, MULTICAST,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:25:90bd:b6:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: en02 shows <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:25:90bd:b6:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:

Comment: @Bib eno1 is  ethernet line and eno2 is a  fiber line

Comment: @rchcoffey What's attached to these interfaces? your setup, honestly, makes very little sense, unless you want your computer to be router to a few specific IPv4 addresses within the same 192.168.0.0/16 subnet, but then it would be much more logical to use use two addresses that do not only differ in exactly the last bit. What's the problem you're actually solving with this IP adress setup? (**not** the problem you're trying to solve that you get *due* to this IP addresses.)

Comment: they are attached to other computer , the reqerment is one 10 G fibre  line and one 1G ethernet line

Comment: I think you are trying to setup the pc as a bridge, but it would be better as a router. with each interface and lan in a different subnet.

Answer (score 5):

For improved efficiency, the Linux network driver stack works on [the Weak Host Model design principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), and that is known to cause problems when you connect two *separate* physical network interfaces to the same network segment.

Those problems will be avoided if you follow three rules:

- If you just need more bandwidth than a single physical network interface can provide and/or fault tolerance, you should *bond* or *team* multiple interfaces together, so that there will be one and only one master network interface object for each directly connected network segment.
- If some of the systems that are supposed to be in the same network segment are only reachable via network interface A, and others only via network interface B, then you'll need to configure a *bridge*, and configure the IP address(es) this system is supposed to use to the bridge object instead of the individual interfaces.
- If you need to provide service on multiple IP addresses of the same network segment, you should always add the extra addresses to the one network interface that is already connected to the segment, instead of naively connecting extra uncoordinated network interfaces to the same segment. This "one interface per segment" can be a regular physical NIC, a bond, a team, or a bridge.

Comment: bonding/teaming should also be the way to go if they just want fault tolerance (and not more bandwidth as such)